# Understanding Java's injection framework HK2?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, hk2

I'm converting an OSGi system into a non-OSGi one, and I have a few services that used to be managed by OSGi. I'I'm trying to use HK2 to inject service implementations in a few classes.

I created a custom injection annotation, and created an `InjectResolver` for it. Then I extended `AbstractBinder` and used the `bind` method to link my annotation to my custom injection resolver. Great.

But now, how do I make the system use this binder??

If I were using HK2 with Jersey, I'd register this binder in Jersey's `ResoureConfig`. But this is not a Jersey application.

How do I tell Hk2 to use my binder so it knows about my custom annotation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use any one of these:

https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ServiceLocatorUtilities.html#bind%28org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder...%29

https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ServiceLocatorUtilities.html#bind%28org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator,%20org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder...%29

https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ServiceLocatorUtilities.html#bind%28java.lang.String,%20org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.Binder...%29

There are several other API in ServiceLocatorUtilities designed to make adding/removing services from HK2 easy.  In general HK2 is very dynamic, so there are many other ways to add/remove services.  The *base* of all of them is the DynamicConfigurationService:

https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/DynamicConfigurationService.html